# What is the difference between a Trans-Mars Injection and a Mars Transfer Orbit?

Tags: mars, rockets, delta-v, simulation, hohmann-transfer

So I'm using  [this](https://transfercalculator.com) transfer orbit calculator and when simulating a transfer from LEO to Mars, in the delta-v breakdown, appear two different values: TMI (Trans-Mars Injection), at around 3000 m/s, and MTO (Mars Transfer Orbit), at around 600 m/s.

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3):

Confusing wording, in my opinion. See also e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliocentric_orbit#Trans-Mars_injection):

> A trans-Mars injection (TMI) is a heliocentric orbit in which a propulsive maneuver is used to set a spacecraft on a trajectory, **also known as Mars transfer orbit**, which will place it as far as Mars orbit. [emphasis added]

However, the numbers you give agree with [this answer analysing the same trajectory](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12660/delta-v-to-low-mars-orbit). This leads me to conclude that the "TMI $\Delta v$" is for the transfer injection burn (leaving LEO into an elliptical trajectory intersecting Mars' orbit) while the "MTO $\Delta v$" is the burn after arriving at Mars in order to enter Mars orbit.